# List unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dpkg

How to show unmet dependencies for some .deb package (e.g. other packages that are needed but not installed or too old) without installing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have unmet dependencies, you won't be able to install the package anyway.
You can try to install it using `dpkg --install`. It will show the unmet dependencies.

To be quite sure the package won't be installed, you can use `--dry-run` or `--simulate` switch.